# 2 or more sub-templates in BI Publisher

Tags: templates, peoplesoft, bi-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

Can 2 or more sub-templates be added to a main template in BI Publisher?

We have a requirement where we need to separate out Addresses and Personal details of a client for re-use in various templates. I tried calling 2 sub-templates (in different RTF files) by passing the input parameter into both of them but only 1 sub-template gets populated at a time. Here is the sample code.

```
<?import:file:/Users/sr/Desktop/TEST_CLIENT_ADDR.rtf?>
<?import:file:/Users/sr/Desktop/TEST_CLIENT.rtf?>
<?param@begin:EmplID?>
<?call@inlines:Client_Addr?><?with-param:EmplID;./EMPLOYEE?><?end call?>
<?call@inlines:Client_Dtls?><?with-param:EmplID;./EMPLOYEE?><?end call?>
```

The sub-template call is as below

```
<?template:Client_Addr?><?param:EmplID;string(‘0002’)?>
Employee : EMPLID
<?end Client_Addr?>
```

Comment: Directly answering your question, yes you can. Which tools are you? Is your data source a Query?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a full example with tools 8.54...

> http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E58500_01/pt854pbh1/eng/pt/txml/task_UsingRTFTemplates-997f94.html#topofpage

Take a look, I have done it before following this example.